# Install4j + Mac Folder: Why is there no option to install a JRE only if it's not present?

Tags: java, macos, install4j

Why doesn't the Mac OS X Folder media file have an option to only install the bundled JRE if the system does not have one? The Windows and Linux media files have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This feature has indeed not been implemented in the Mac OS X installer. I have added it to the issue tracker.